# How to force the common change event for jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, onchange

I'm using the [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) plugin the common way:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo")
        .autocomplete({
            autoFocus : true,
            delay : 500,
            minLength : 0,
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.get(
                    "/order/ajax/foo?"
                    + "data[foo]=" + $('#foo').val(),
                    {},
                    function(data) {
                        response(data.slice(0, 10));
                    }
                );
            }
        }).on('focus', function(event) {
            console.log(new Date());
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).autocomplete("search", this.value);
        });
});

$(function() {
    $("#foo")
        .autocomplete({
            autoFocus : true,
            delay : 500,
            minLength : 0,
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.get(
                    "/order/ajax/bar?"
                    + "data[foo]=" + $('#foo').val()
                    + "data[bar]=" + $('#bar').val(),
                    {},
                    function(data) {
                        response(data.slice(0, 10));
                    }
                );
            }
        }).on('focus', function(event) {
            console.log(new Date());
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).autocomplete("search", this.value);
        });
});
```

Since there are dependencies between different fields (e.g. `bar` on `foo`), I want to reset/clear the dependent field, when their "master"-fields get updated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fieldFoo = $('#foo');
    fieldBar = $("#bar");
});

function updateFooDependentFields(value) {
    alert('test updateBarDependentFields');
    fieldBar.val('');
}
```

Now the issue: It works only if I've *typed* someting in `foo`. If I've only `focus`ed it and chosen another autosuggested entry, the `change` event is not triggered and the dependending fields (e.g. `bar`) don't get cleared. Why?

**How to force triggering the *common* change event for jQuery autocomplete?**

---

**Workaround 1**

It's possible to define the `onChange` actions in the Autocomplete settings, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo")
        .autocomplete({
            autoFocus : true,
            delay : 500,
            minLength : 0,
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.get(
                    "/order/ajax/bar?"
                    + "data[foo]=" + $('#foo').val()
                    + "data[bar]=" + $('#bar').val(),
                    {},
                    function(data) {
                        response(data.slice(0, 10));
                    }
                );
            },
            // here
            change: function (event, ui) { updateFooDependentFields(); }
        })
        // or here
        .on('change', function(event) {
            updateFooDependentFields();
        })
    ;
});
```

But the `change` event is not a specific of the autocompletion. So if I want tomorrow to remove the autocompletion I don't want to keep in mind, that it might affect functionality, that is not related with it. That's why I'm looking for a way to define the `onChange` "listener" outside the autocomplete definition block.

A further weak point of this solution is, the the `change` event works only in the context of the autocomplete. That means e.g.: If I change the autocomplete field's value fast (so that the autocomplete is not triggered) and directly after it go out of the field, the `change` event doesn't get triggered, though the field has been changed.

**Workaround 2**

Another way is to trigger the `change` event from the `autocompletechange` event, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    foo.on('autocompletechange', function() {
        console.log('autocompletechange');
        foo.trigger('change');
    });
    foo.change(function() {
        console.log('change');
        updateFooDependentFields(this.value);
    });
});
```

Now the actions I want to be performed on `change` are defined at one place outside of the autocomplete context, so I don't need to keep in mind side effects, if I remove autocomplete. But in the cases, when I *type* something in the field, the `change` event gets triggered twice -- once, because I've changed the field value typing there something, and once more, because the `autocompletechange` triggered the `change` event.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ didn't help?

Comment: @manu29.d The `change` event should be triggered every time, when the `value` of the field gets changed. The problem now is, that it doesn't work as expected (or better: doesn't work at all), when the `value` has been changed without typing. I have no idea, where to trigger the `change` event. It should work "automatically" when the `value` has been updated and the user has left the field (so that it's inactive / not `focus`ed).

Comment: I want to say the chained `.on('change')` event is different from the change event internal to the autocomplete. It seems the chained change event fires before the value has been updated by the selected autocomplete entry where as the change event internal to the autocomplete fires after update. Could be wrong though.